# v-menu: v-text-field in activator slot disappears when pushing route in nuxt project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxtjs

In my nuxt project i use Vuetify. I take date from users and when user changed page by clicking save button, v-text-field dissapears before page changed, before going next page . It is because of route changing but i could not find a solution for this problem.

```
<v-menu v-model="menu"
            :close-on-content-click="false"
           transition="scale-transition"
           rounded
           nudge-bottom="60px"
           min-width="290px">

       <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
           <v-text-field :value="formatDateText"
                         label="Birth Date"
                         v-bind="attrs"
                         v-on="on"
                         offset-y
                         hide-details>
           </v-text-field>
       </template>
       <v-date-picker no-title
                       v-model="date"
                       @change="dateChangeFormat(formatDate)"
              
       />
     </v-menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found 2 solutions for this problem . first solution is use

```
 features: {
    transitions: false
  },
```

inside the nuxt.config.js

Second solution : add ref to v-menu .

```
   <v-menu v-model="menu"
            ref="menu"
            :close-on-content-click="false"
            transition="scale-transition"
            rounded
            nudge-bottom="60px"
            min-width="290px">
```

in script area ;

```
   beforeDestroy() {
        this.$refs.menu.activatorNode = null;
    },
```